# How too keep background color in margins of pdf pages generated by Puppeteer?

Tags: pdf, puppeteer, margin

I am generating pdf documents using Puppeteer, from page with dynamic content.

I want to add margins below and above the text (content) in consecutive pages.

When I use the property margin:

```
@page {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

it adds margins, but the background color of the margin is white.

Is there a way to only apply margins to the text and keep the background color?
Since this is dynamic data, we cant add the padding property on the content.

Screenshot of pdf generated without margin:
[image]

and with margin:
[image]

Comment: Try padding instead of margin or set the parent container background to the same color as the child? If that doesn't work, a [mcve] would be great, showing your sample page and runnable Puppeteer code. This saves everyone time rewriting your work, clarifies the problem, and gets you faster and more accurate responses. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe a shot in the dark, but there is a posibility of modifying your page with `await page.addStyleTag({ YOUR_CSS_HERE })` before saving it as a PDF file. Maybe u could set a background-color to `<html>` or idk what elements to make it work  :)